How do I correctly add a file name to a window title in SwiftUI and allow my toolbar to be centered in the title bar
For MacOS, I add this to my main VStack in my ContentView and while I get the fileName my toolbars are jammed on the right side.
.onAppear {
    if let window = NSApplication.shared.windows.first {
        window.title = "fileName"
    }
}

I know that my toolbars are correctly defined since when I add this line to the onAppear my toolbars are perfectly centered.
window.titleVisibility = .hidden

It appears that the default file name area has a huge Spacer that divides the Title Bar space in 1/2.  I started my project with a default SwiftUI project.  Is there a way to get rid of that giant Spacer in the default area?
Edit-1
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            ToolbarView( dm )
                .navigationTitle("fileNamexxx")
...

If I set window.titleVisibility = .hidden I get No file Name with my toolbar properly centered:

If I don't hide the title I get this:

I need to center my tool set in the middle of the title bar as it is above another button bar that is centered.
Edit-2:
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var fileName = "Untitled"

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Your Content Here")
                .padding()
        }
        .frame(minWidth: 200, minHeight: 100)
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        .background(Color.white)
        .overlay(
            CustomTitleBar(fileName: $fileName)
                .frame(height: 30)
                .background(Color.gray)
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
        )
        .onAppear {
            if let window = NSApplication.shared.windows.first {
                window.title = fileName
                window.titleVisibility = .hidden
                window.titlebarAppearsTransparent = true
            }
        }
    }
}

struct CustomTitleBar: View {
    @Binding var fileName: String

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text(fileName)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .padding(.leading, 8)
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}


Can we assume this is a macos app?

I don't believe iOS applications have title bars so yes you can.  I'm I wrong there?

WoW, I was tired last night when I answered that.  Yes, the application is a MacOS application.  I'll add another tag if I can for MacOS.

Thanks for adding the tag. Also, I believe .navigationTitle("fileName") added to the top of the view hierarchy will have the desired effect on macos apps like the window.title, per Apple's docs on navigationTitle. So navigationTitle compiles with both ios and mac.

Hummm... navigationTile() is more concise and does provide a file name in the title bar.  Unfortunately, I have the same issue where is a large spacer pushing my toolbars to the right side.  So I have added Edit-1 above to show how I'm adding those.

@Marcy any idea how to resolve this?

No, I tried a few things but didn’t find a satisfactory solution.

Thanks for trying... I tried using NS instead and it destroyed the Title Bar.  No Window Widgets and the FileName font and placement was pretty bad.  It also added dead space below my current Tool Set.  I was hoping I did something wrong or there was a way to say don't include the Spacer.

The images you added help illustrate the problem much better. Seems like the formatting is something we can't tap into.

@Marcy Edit-2 allows me to remove the current faux file name and the toolbar does center BUT the FileName shows up in the far left vertical middle of my content area instead of after the widgets in the title bar but it has the wrong font and size.

Use the navigationTitle modifier to put the document name in the title bar.
Use the navigationDocument modifier to put the document proxy icon in the title bar.
Use ToolbarItemGroup(placement: principal) { ... } to position items in the center of the toolbar (space permitting).

The code:
struct ContentView: View {
    @Binding var tool: Tool

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image(systemName: "globe")
                .imageScale(.large)
                .foregroundStyle(.tint)
            Text("Hello, world!")
        }
        .padding()
        .navigationDocument(URL(fileURLWithPath: "/tmp/Untitled.txt"))
        .navigationTitle("Untitled")
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .principal) {
                Picker("Tools", selection: $tool) {
                    ForEach(Tool.allCases) {
                        Label($0.name, systemImage: $0.systemImage)
                    }
                }
                .pickerStyle(.inline)
            }
        }
        .buttonStyle(.accessoryBar)
        .frame(minWidth: 600, minHeight: 300)
    }
}

enum Tool: Hashable, Identifiable, CaseIterable {
    case select
    case text
    case line
    case circle
    case square

    var id: Self { self }

    var name: LocalizedStringKey {
        return switch self {
        case .select: "Select"
        case .text: "Text"
        case .line: "Line"
        case .circle: "Circle"
        case .square: "Square"
        }
    }

    var systemImage: String {
        return switch self {
        case .select: "cursorarrow"
        case .text: "textformat"
        case .line: "line.diagonal"
        case .circle: "circle"
        case .square: "square"
        }
    }

    var key: KeyEquivalent? {
        return switch self {
        case .select: "a"
        case .text: "t"
        case .line: "l"
        case .circle: "c"
        case .square: "s"
        }
    }
}

@main
struct testApp: App {
    @State var tool: Tool = .select

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView(tool: $tool)
        }
        .commands {
            CommandMenu("Tools") {
                ForEach(Tool.allCases) { candidate in
                    Toggle(isOn: .init(
                        get: { tool == candidate },
                        set: { _ in tool = candidate }
                    )) {
                        Text(candidate.name)
                    }
                    .keyboardShortcut(candidate.key.map { KeyboardShortcut($0, modifiers: []) })
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


TY!! it was your usage of principal that must have moved it from the right side to the left side of the TitleBar.  After posting this I found navigationTitle() but still had issues with centering the main toolbar.  Perfect TY so much.
